# How to check if a relation is in BCNF

Tags: relational-database, functional-dependencies, bcnf

I have a relation:`A,B,C,D,E`

with FD:

```
A->BC      

CD->E

B->D

E->A
```

Since `A->BC` can be `A->B`, `A->C`, then `B->D` can become `A->D`. And since `A->C` and `A->D`, then `CD->E` can become `A->E`. I am not sure about `E->A` but since `A->E` then I would assume it would be `A->A` and become a trivial FD. That means the key for this relation would be `{A}`? So the only FD given that has `A` on the left side would be `A->BC`.

But is this relation in BCNF? If not, how would I change it to become BCNF? I have read that I am to use FD that violate BCNF as a starting point to separate a relation, so would I select a FD that doesn't have A on the left and keep separating there?

Comment: Actually found the answer to my question on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692318/bcnf-decomposition?rq=1

Comment: Vague shorthands like "can become" make both understanding and communication difficult. Nothing is becoming anything else here. Tolerating such vagueness in reasoning is what leads to not understanding. (Also, when you list the "becomings" you don't say what the point is.) PS If you want to know if it's in BCNF, what *definition* of BCNF were you given? If  you want to "change it" (again, nothing is *changing* except what you are using for what purpose), what *algorithm* for producing a BCNF design were you given?